# Is there a better way to return an empty string only if there is no value or return a value if there is one in a short way?

Tags: python, mysql

So basically I want to return an empty string if the query's result is None and return the value from the result if there is one.

I tried using

```
return '' if x is None else x
```

and

```
return x or ''
```

That's how my function looks like:

```
def get_token_status(self):
    query = 'SELECT used FROM tokens WHERE token = %s'
    self.cursor.execute(query, (self.token,))
    return self.cursor.fetchone()['used'] # // return '' or x // return '' if x is None else x
```

and that's how my cursor instance looks like:

```
cursor = db.cursor(dictionary=True)
```

and thanks to the dictionary parameter the cursor.fetchone() returns a dictionary with the values so that's why I use square brackets here

I also printed the value of cursor.fetchone() from the query and it printed out

```
None
```

if there were no rows in the result and:

```
{'used': '1'}
```

if there were rows in the result. I get the TypeError error:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

I tried catching the error in a try block when I'm calling the function and it worked, though I think there's a better and shorter way of doing so.

Thanks for all the help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the object is a `dict` or possibly `None`, you can do:

```
return (self.cursor.fetchone() or {}).get('used', '')
```

Comment: Ah man! I wish it would work, when I saw it I really thought it might, but unfortunately, if there are no results from the query then the cursor.fetchone() is somehow None and it has no attribute get, but when there are it works perfectly.

Comment: @Aliann Whoops! I even understood it that way, then forgot to handle it. I just updated my response. Basically, if the result comes back as None, then the `or {}` makes the result in the brackets an empty dict to which `get` can be applied.

Comment: Thank you very much, not it works! Its been bugging me for hours now! Thanks once again.